# My jQuery Code doesn't work with Sticky footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my Sticky footer while using jQuery. The reason why I use jQuery is because it's a "Demand" so I have to use it.

Here is my jQuery Code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var bodyHeight = $("body").height();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        if (windowHeight > bodyHeight) {
            $("Footer").css("position", "absolute").css("bottom", 0);
        }
    });
```

You can Check the problem on [My site](http://medieproduktion.mediacollege.dk:10157/GFP/)

It sticks to the button of the page when then content is not bigger than the site, but then when it "breaks" when the Content gets longer than the window site.

hope you can help me and not refer to another page that use CSS, as I said, I have to use jQuery

Thanks again

Comment: Using jQuery to set css styling is definitely awkward. Who set that stupid policy? Nevertheless the styling needed should be the same regardless of contained in a CSS file or applied with jQuery `css()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

So you need to apply like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var bodyHeight = $(document).height();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        if (bodyHeight > windowHeight) {
            $("Footer").css("position", "absolute").css("bottom", 0);
        }
    });
```

Replace to `(windowHeight > bodyHeight)` with `(bodyHeight > windowHeight)`

---

And also be assure about the selector `Footer`

Answer (score 0):

You have real problems here:

1. It is a really strange idea to use jQuery for that. Why not use existing tutorial? e.g. [tutorial](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) with even points about asp.net
2. Your code will always cover its part of page: the footer has some height and this height will be taken out from content, it is a bad style of sticky footer to not think about that

Use another way of doing the task.